# Why I always get "No tests were found" "Class not found: xxx" when running the defualt local unit ExampleUnitTest class on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, testing, junit

I'm trying to use Unit testing using JUnit in my android project, so I tried to run the ExampleUnitTest class in the (test) folder with this statement:

```
Assert.assertEquals(4,5)
```

and it passed I don't know why then I created another class in the same folder and now I get the error even on the ExampleUnitTest class

> No tests where found
> with a message
> Class not found: "{{packageName}}.ExampleUnitTest"

This is the ExampleUnitTest class
[ExampleUnitTest class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA5gd.png)

This is the configuration
[ExampleUnitTest configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpwdR.png)

Using this dependency:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
```